# jQuery input mask adds extra characters on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-inputmask, input-mask

Using `jquery-inputmask` [plugin](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) 
I have a mask for phone input field:

```
$("#phone").inputmask({
    mask : '+7 (999) 999-99-99',
    clearmaskonlostfocus : false,
    removeMaskOnSubmit : true,
    autoUnmask : true
});
```

`<input type="tel">`

Should look this way `+7 (___) ___-__-__`
and accept only digits.

Works fine on desktop browser,
but on mobile (chrome on Android for example)
every time I input a digit it adds extra 7 to it..

Pressing key 1:
`+7 (71_) ___-__-__`

Pressing key 2:
`+7 (771) 2__-__-__`

Pressing key 3
`+7 (777) 123-__-__`
e.t.c

What can I possibly do wrong?

Comment: it's [known issue](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/issues/1650)